# jquery check for empty node

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DOM element as follows;

```
<div id="myDiv">
<jstl:tag1 />
<jstl:tag2 />
</div>
```

Now as you can see, I have a JSTL tags which can return some text value.

I need to finally check if my DOM element "myDiv" is empty using jQuery..

Unfortunately I cannot do a simple `$("#myDiv").html() == ""` as even if the JSTL tags do not retun any value, I get new line chars inside the div as \n and all

How do I account for those check for empty node?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Contains no non whitespace text nodes?

Comment: hey Testndtv - see my answer, you can .trim away the newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a regex test

```
/\w+/.test($("#myDiv").html())
```

It will test for at least one word character like alpha-numerical character.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
$('#myDiv').html().trim() == "";
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, Use text() instead of html()

```
 $("#myDiv").text().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test the number of non whitespace nodes inside the element:

```
var nodes = $('#myDiv')[0].childNodes;
var nonempty = [];
for(i=0; i<nodes.length;i++){
    if(nodes[i].nodeType !== 3 || nodes[i].nodeValue.trim() !== "" ){
        nonempty.push(nodes[i]);
    }
}

//this should be 0 if empty
alert(nonempty.length);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/DWx8R/

Answer (score 0):

```
var isEmpty = $.trim( $('#myDiv').text() ).length === 0;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WBU4a/)